# What capabilities does systemd daemon require to create cgroups?

Tags: systemd, cgroups, linux-capabilities

In my project I need sometimes to be able to create new control groups as an unprivileged user. I decided to write a systemd daemon for this.

I use [libcgroup](https://github.com/matsumotory/libcgroup) in the daemon code for cgroup manipulation.

When I try to create a cgroup (`cgroup_create_cgroup`), I receive a libcgroup error `ECGROUPNOTALLOWED` (`Cgroup, operation not allowed`). How to allow my daemon to create new cgroups?

systemd .service file:

```
[Service]
...
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_SYS_ADMIN
PrivateTmp=yes
PrivateDevices=yes
PrivateNetwork=yes
ProtectSystem=yes
ProtectHome=yes
ProtectControlGroups=no
ProtectKernelTunables=no
RestrictRealtime=no
User=root
Group=root
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't really know which of those protections was odd but just removing them all did the trick.